# rmakrdown latex display equation

Tags: r, latex, equation, r-markdown

I'm having trouble getting rmarkdown to generate a latex display equation in .docx output, even while the same code generates a correct .pdf (with equation).

This is some sample .Rmd code which generates the problem:

````
# Stuff
Blah blah blah.

```{r blurb_1}
test.xy <- matrix(c(runif(10,10,30),runif(10,70,90)),ncol=2,byrow=T)
plot(test.xy)
```

As the data are a set of points 
$p_{1 \cdots n}=(x_{1} \cdots x_{n},y_{1} \cdots
y_{n})$, a measure of difference is the distance 
between any two points,$p_{i},p_{j}$,

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{(x_{i}-x_{j})^2+(y_{i}-y_{j})^2} 
\end{equation}

```{r blurb_2}
di <- dist.mat(test.xy[,1],test.xy[,2]) # a distance matrix
dim(di)
```
Of course, blah blah.
````

When running it from within R

```
rmarkdown::render(file.choose(),"pdf_document")
```

generates the equation but

```
rmarkdown::render(file.choose(),"word_document")
```

doesn't!    Can anyone direct me on how to make the latex equation appear in the .docx output?

Any help solving what must be a basic error on my part will be most appreciated! (I'm using R 3.1.1, the `rmarkdown` package 0.5.1 and have `pandoc` 1.13.2, e.g. all up to date.)

Comment: word uses its own equation editor. there are several resources on google for using latex in word, but it doesn't fully support tex out-of-the-box afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use $$ instead of \begin and \end equation:

```
$$\sqrt{(x_{i}-x_{j})^2+(y_{i}-y_{j})^2}$$
```

Comment: my rep isn't high enough to give you an up-vote, but **thanks** for clearing up my misunderstanding of $$.

Comment: If you are the one asking the question, the point is to accept the best answer. Click the check mark near where the up/down vote is to "accept" an answer as the solution.

Comment: Is there some way to make this work with equation numbers?